# Syntax Error in simple Python code

Tags: python, powershell, syntax-error

I found an exercise online to make a specific program, kinda got lost writing, and forgot to test for far too long. Now the program is spitting out an error - and a very strange one, at that.

I didn't know how much of it to post, but I'm putting it all out here just in case.

```
import math
print "Hey. Do you want to activate the hypothenuse program, or the diagonals one?"
print "[1] Hypothenuse"
print "[2] Diagonals"
program_chosen = raw_input()

if program_chosen == "1":

    print """
        Hello. This is a simple math program to determine the length of the hypothenuse of
        a right triangle given the other two sides. The results will be rounded to three decimal
        places, to avoid confusion.
        """
    # Once the other problems have been dealt with, implement a "choose digits rounded" option.
    side1 = int(raw_input("Please enter the length of any of the non-hypothenuse sides of the triangle. "))
    side2 = int(raw_input("Now, enter the length of the other side. "))
    pythagoras = math.sqrt((side1**2)+(side2**2))
    # Need to define another variable to choose the number of rounded-to digits.
    print "The length of the hypothenuse is , approximately, " + str((round(pythagoras, 3))) + "."  

elif program_chosen == "2":
    print """
        Very well. The following program is one which, given an n-sided polygon, finds the number
        of diagonals formed by its vertexes.
        """ 
    n_of_sides = int(raw_input("To start, please enter the number of sides of the polygon. "))
    if n_of_sides < 3
        print "That isn't a polygon, silly! Please try again."
        # Need to find a way to repeat the prompt until a valid number of sides is inputted.
        # Probably a While loop, but haven't learned how to use one effectively yet.
        # Apparently a goto is not good programming form. :(
        exit()
    else
        n_of_diagonals = (n_of_sides*(n_of_sides-3))/2
        print " A %d sided polygon has %d diagonals." % (n_of_sides, n_of_diagonals)

else:
    print "That is not a valid option. Please try again."
    # Here, too, need to implement a "try again" option.
    exit()
```

The thing is, when running it, PowerShell told me the line 7 `if` statement breaks (SyntaxError: invalid syntax) because I'm using a single equals sign (which I found was a variable setter and not a comparison), but even after changing it to a double equals one the error continued appearing. So I tried it again, just to be sure, on afterhours' code tester, and a "ParseError: bad input on line 27" error appeared.

So I'm really confused. Please help?

Comment: You forgot the `:` at the end of your condition.

Comment: If you're running/pasting this inside a PowerShell (the shell), it'll be parsed as PowerShell (the language), not Python

Comment: @Vincent Savard: Welp, I'm an idiot. You're right, the program works perfectly now. Also, the SyntaxError on line seven was because I was running another, older version of the program where I hadn't changed it to a double equal signs yet. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen: Yeah, made that mistake a while ago. Calling python hypot_diag.py now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, you missed two colons:

```
    if n_of_sides < 3: #######
        print "That isn't a polygon, silly! Please try again."
        # Need to find a way to repeat the prompt until a valid number of sides is inputted.
        # Probably a While loop, but haven't learned how to use one effectively yet.
        # Apparently a goto is not good programming form. :(
        exit()
    else:  #####
```